# Why to rails redirects work when redirecting to a route and do not work when redirecting to an action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-routing, controllers

I have been struggling with rails double render errors for a few weeks now (Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action. Please note that you may only call render OR redirect, and at mos ....etc...).

I figured out that if i have a statement like this:

```
redirect_to action_name and return
```

I get the double render error.  However, when i specify a route called action_name_path, and do a statement like this:

```
redirect_to action_name_path
```

I don't get the double render error anymore.  Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The redirect_to should be use to go to another controller or to a external web page and automatically returns something...

When use the redirect_to you need to specify the controller and action that you want to render. You can do that by calling the route (action_name_path(:params[])).

When you want to call other method in the same controller or render a different view you don't need to render the controller, instead of redirect_to you can use render method.

Please see the documentation

- [redirect_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html)
- [render](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-by-default-convention-over-configuration-in-action)